# BigQuery/Tableau Date Error: Invalid date: 'Feb 5, 2021'

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, tableau-api

I guess big query does not like the date format of my data, I was looking for ideas on how to convert it.

I'm using Tableau.

```
The Google BigQuery service was unable to compile the query.
Error Code: 015CFBE6
Invalid date: 'Feb 5, 2021'
```

Comment: You should provide an example of your data to make it more clear. Is all your date column in the same format ?

Answer (score 0):

In the case you report, we can parse your date with the following:

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%b %d, %Y', 'Feb 5, 2021') AS my_date
```

`%b` indicates the shortened version of the month name.
The information about the supported date elements can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#supported_format_elements_for_date).